# Usage of scanf in while loop

Tags: c

I have to read a series of input from a file using scanf. But there are different outcomes in 2 situations.
**Code1**- Reading an integer and a char array.

```
char plaintext[20];
int started = 0;
int x;


while (scanf("%i,%19[^\n]",&x,plaintext) == 2)
{
    if (started == 1)
        printf(",\n");
    else 
            started = 1;
    printf("i read a line from a file");
}
printf("\n");
```

This works perfectly fine. The scanf reads every line in the file and the printf() outputs the required line for each line input.

**Code2**-Reading only a char array

```
char plaintext[20];
int started = 0;

while (scanf("%19[^\n]",plaintext) == 1)
{
    if (started == 1)
        printf(",\n");
    else 
            started = 1;
    printf("i read a line from a file");
}
printf("\n");
```

Here, the scanf reads only the first line and prints "i read a line from a file" only once.Why??

One solution is using %*c in scanf in Code 2. But why Code 1 works fine, but not Code 2.

Comment: A newlines left in the previous input will be rejected with the next entry. `"%19[^\n]"` --> `"%19[^\n]%*c"`

Answer (score 2):

You need to change

```
scanf("%19[^\n]",plaintext)
```

so that it reads the new line character that is in the buffer after reading the first line.

Try

```
scanf("%19[^\n] ",plaintext)
```

The space reads the new line character at the end of the line

Comment: Sir could we use '\r'  instead of space there?

Comment: [scanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) - From this page *A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline, etc.; see isspace(3)). This directive matches any amount of white space, including none, in the input.* - So yes

Comment: But why such new line character reading is not required in Code1 but is necessary in Code2.

Comment: The `%i` will consume the white space in code1. Code 2 `%19[^\n]` does not consume the new line character